# Does each shard in Ethereum 2.0 have its own address space?

Tags: evm, sharding

Sharding is planned for Ethereum 2.0, which will split the state into a few hundred shards, connected along a [hypercube network topology](https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/10/21/scalability-part-2-hypercubes/).

Does each shard have its own address space, or, is there a global address space?

Comment: Sharding is still very experimental, and AFAIK only thoughts/musings by Ethereum developers have been posted, without any type of proof that it will work/be stable. So I doubt there is a firm answer to your question, but the developers state that shards will be able to communicate with each other (cross shard) so this would mean there is some type of global identifier/address space.

Answer (score 1):

There is a shard ID for each shard that is a prefix to the address. For details, see https://ethresear.ch/t/minimal-sharding-protocol-extension/1823 and https://github.com/Drops-of-Diamond/diamond_drops/issues/13 for updates.